# How to create report textbox aggregate expression in SQL server reporting with multiple datasets

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

If have a SQL Server Reporting Services report that has several textboxes within a Report with variations of the following expression

```
=Sum(IiF(Fields!RegisterID.Value = 6000, 1, 0)
```

and

```
Iif(Fields!PointID.Value = 500, 1, 0)) / Sum(Iif(Fields!PointID.Value = 500, 1, 0))
```

I see the following error when I try to preview the report:

> The Value expression for the text box ‘Textbox2’ uses an aggregate expression without a scope. A scope is required for all aggregates used outside of a data region unless the report contains exactly one dataset.

How do I fix This?

Answer (score 16):

As per the error, when you are referencing a Dataset field in a textbox that isn't part of a table, you need to specify a Scope for expression, e.g. you want a field, but what Dataset should be used?

So something like:

```
=Sum(IiF(Fields!RegisterID.Value = 6000, 1, 0), "MyDataset")
```

Where `MyDataset` is the name of a Dataset in your report.

If you are doing this in an independent textbox, you must also use an aggregate function like `First` or `Sum`, as only one value can be displayed in the textbox and the Dataset might have multiple rows; using an aggregate makes sure only one values is returned, as required.